# Verilog: Minimal (hardware) algorithm for multiplying a binary input to its delayed form

Tags: algorithm, verilog, hdl

I have a binary input `in` (1 bit serial input) which I want to delay by `M` clock pulses and then multiply (AND) the 2 signals. In other words, I want to evaluate the sum:

```
sum(in[n]*in[n+M])
```

where `n` is expressed in terms of number of clock pulses.

The most straightforward way is to store in a memory buffer `in_dly` the latest `M` samples of `in`. In Verilog, this would be something like:

```
always @(posedge clock ...)
    ...
    in_dly[M-1:0] <= {in_dly[M-2:0], in}; 
    if (in_dly[M-1] & in)
         sum <= sum + 'd1;
    ...
```

While this works in theory, with large values of `M` (can be ~2000), the size of the buffer   is not practical. However, I was thinking to take advantage of the fact that the input signal is 1 bit and it is expected to toggle only a few times (~1-10) during `M` samples.

This made me think of storing the toggle times from `2k*M` to `(2k+1)*M` in an array `a` and from `(2k+1)*M` to `(2k+2)*M` in an array `b` (`k` is just an integer used to generalize the idea):

```
reg [10:0]      a[0:9];     //2^11 > max(M)=2000  and "a" has max 10 elements
reg [10:0]      b[0:9];     //same as "a"
```

Therefore, during `M` samples, `in = 'b1` during intervals `[a[1],a[2]], [a[3],a[4]], etc`. Similarly, during the next `M` samples, the input is high during `[b[1],b[2]], [b[3],b[4]], etc`. Now, the sum is the "overlapping" of these intervals:

```
min(b[2],a[2])-max(b[1],a[1]), if b[2]>a[1] and b[1]<a[2]; 0 otherwise
```

Finally, the array `b` becomes the new array `a` and the next `M` samples are evaluated and stored into `b`. The process is repeated until the end of `in`.

Comparing this "optimized" method to the initial one, there is a significant gain in hardware: initially 2000 bits were stored, and now 220 bits are stored (for this example). However, the number is still large and not very practical..

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could suggest a more optimal (hardware-wise) way or a simpler way (algorithm-wise) of doing this operation. Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Thanks to Alexey's idea, I optimized the algorithm as follows:

Given a set of delays `M[i] for i=1 to 10 with M[1]<M[2]<..<M[10]`, and an input binary array `in`, we need to compute the outputs:

`y[i] = sum(in[n]*in[n+M[i]]) for n=1 to length(in)`.

We then define 2 empty arrays `a[j]` and `b[j]` with `j=1,~5`. Whenever `in` has a `0->1` transition, the smallest index empty element `a[j]` is "activated" and will increment at each clock cycle. Same goes for `b[j]` at `1->0` transitions. Basically, the pairs `(a[j],b[j])` represent the portions of `in` equal to 1.

Whenever `a[j]` equals `M[i]`, the sum `y[i]` will increment by 1 at each cycle while `in = 1`, until `b[j]` equals `M[i]`. Once `a[j]` equals `M[10]`, `a[j]` is cleared. Same goes for `b[j]`. This is repeated until the end of `in`.

Based on the same numerical assumptions as the initial question, a total of 10 arrays (`a` and `b`) of 11 bits allow the computation of the 10 sums, corresponding to 10 different delays `M[i]`. This is almost 20 times better (in terms of resources used) than my initial approach. Any further optimization or idea is welcomed!

Comment: Is the operation `sum(in[n]*in[n+M])` only made once in your design, or multiple times so the saving for each will be done multiple times?  Is `M` a constant for the implementation, or it it change over time?  If the implementation is in a FPGA, then the LUTs can usually implement very effective shift registers, so doing `in[n+M]` a single time will not require 2000 flip-flops, but merely 30 LUTs, so simply paying the cost for the shift may be worth it, compared to spending time on a more complex design.

Comment: Hi Morten. The sum is computed multiple times (~10, while n = 1 to ~60000) and M is a constant for each sum. Actually, the sums are used for computing the autocorrelation of "in".
The application is an ASIC, having a custom digital part and a small memory available. Therefore, it is imperative to reduce as much as possible the ressources for this operation.

Comment: With the design property that `in` only has seldom toggles, then a shallow FIFO can be used to transfer the length of 0 and 1 periods, and the `in` with delay of M cycles can then be regenerated.  With 10 toogles in 2000 cycles the FIFO memory will be about 10 * log2(2000) = 110 bits, and then there is some FIFO index overhead.  Not much less than the 220 bits you calculated.  However, this amount of bits is getting close to the amount of information in a signal toggling 10 times in 2000 cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, it is a bit better to buffer the lengths and recreate the delayed signal. Moreover, since the delays M are slightly different for each sum, each will need to be stored separately (M(i) samples, i=1:10) or use some complex logic to recycle the smaller buffers M(i) from the biggest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- make array `A`,
- every time when `in`==1 get free `A` element and write `M` to it.
- every clock decrement all non-zero `A` elements,
- once any decremented element becomes zero, test `in`, if `in`==1 - `sum++`.

Edit: algorithm above intended for input like 
 - 00000000000010000000100010000000, while LLDinu realy needs 
 - 11111111111110000000011111000000, so here is modified algorithm:

- make array (ring buffer) `A`,
- every time when `in` toggles, get free `A` element and write `M` to it.
- every clock decrement all non-zero `A` elements,
- every clock test `in`, if `in`==1 and number of non-zero `A` elements is **even** - `sum++`.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you for the interesting suggestion! I think your idea is good, but it's quite wasteful (in resources/memory) as a large number of elements equal to M (11 bits) would need to be stored. However, it can be optimized as explained in my edit to the question.

Comment: It's clear. I thought input is like 0001000000010000000 while it is 1111100000000111111111000

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but it's not really working. For example, if the delay is similar to the period of the input, then you would almost always have 2 elements in A. Nevertheless, it's very similar to my current approach and uses the same resources, so I might adjust the algorithm, but I'll keep the concept. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If togglings are completely random, I expect my algorithm working well. Are they?

Comment: You are right, I've checked it hastily and made a mistake.